# 4 way switch replacement

Tags: switch, multiway-switch, replacement

I am replacing a 4 way switch, and I'm confused where the wires need to go on the new switch. The old switch had a pair(A) of red and black wires going to 2 terminals labeled line 1, and another pair(B) of red and black wires going to 2 terminals labeled line 2. All 4 terminal screws are brass. There are also neutral wires from each pair that have been tied together but no ground wires.

The new switch has on one side a black screw at the top labeled in and a brass screw at the bottom labeled out. The other side is reversed, with a brass screw at the top labeled out and a black screw at the bottom labeled in.

Any help is appreciated. Also, the new switch has a ground screw. Do I need to find something to ground the switch to? The new switch is an Enerlites brand.

Comment: Model number of new switch? Is the box metal or plastic?

Comment: The new switch is Enerlites 94150-W. The box is plastic

Comment: Can you post photos of the inside of the box in question please?

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include the pictures instead of putting them in the comments where they might not be seen/get deleted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Brass = Line 1 & Black = Line 2 (or the other way around)

Your new switch, like most four-ways, uses the two screw colors to distinguish  between the two "sides" of the switch.  As a result, connect the Line 1 wires to the brass screws and the Line 2 wires to the black screws.  Unfortunately, with a plastic box and no grounding wires, it looks like you'll be stuck having to not ground the switch, though.